# JavaScript drawImage() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Getting into JS game development but bumped into a little problem. The image won't draw. It loads fine, no errors in the console, but it just won't display. What am I missing?

**JS**

```
var Game = {
characterSpeed: 2,
characterHorizontalSpeed: this.characterSpeed,
characterVerticalSpeed: this.characterSpeed,
characterX: 400,
characterY: 500,
mouseX: 0,
mouseY: 0,
gameRunning: false,
debug: true,
characterImg: '',
context: '',

init: function() {
    $('#game').mousemove(function(event) {
        Game.mouseX = event.pageX;
        Game.mouseY = event.pageY;
    });

    Game.context = document.getElementById('game').getContext('2d');

    Game.loadImages();
    Game.game();
},

loadImages: function() {
    Game.characterImg = new Image;
    Game.characterImg.src = 'images/character.png';

    Game.characterImg.onload = function() {
        Game.context.drawImage(Game.characterImg, 400, 500);
    }
},
}

$(function() {
Game.init();
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <div id="inner">
        <canvas id="game" style="background: white; width: 800px; height: 500px;"></canvas>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your canvas size in `width` and `height` attributes not in the style.

```
<div id="inner">
    <canvas id="game" width="800" height="500"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried this to no avail. The image still refuses to display.

Comment: also make sure you call `drawImage` properly, it takes image position as second and third params so maybe your image's just drawn out of bounds?

Comment: That's not the problem. I checked the coords with Google Developer tools.

Comment: well i'm pretty sure if height of your canvas is 500px and then you draw image at the position in your code (400, 500) you won't see it. Try `drawImage(Game.characterImg, 0, 0)`

Comment: Oh! Thanks dmk! I was reading the coordinates of the page, not the canvas. Issue solved, accepted answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the src property at the very last, so after the onload.

```
loadImages: function() {

    Game.characterImg = new Image();

    Game.characterImg.onload = function() {
        Game.context.drawImage(Game.characterImg, 400, 500);
    }

    Game.characterImg.src = 'images/character.png';

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a newbie. Can you elaborate and give an example?

Comment: There you go.. have you checked what your console tells you (in chrome, right click, select "inspect element" then click on console then reload)

Answer (score 0):

The image is probably in your cache, so by the time you set the onload event, the image is already loaded so the onload isn't called.  Simply reverse the order, like this:

```
Game.characterImg.onload = function() {
      Game.context.drawImage(Game.characterImg, 400, 500);
   }
Game.characterImg.src = 'images/character.png';
```